# How can I share a bitmap image between Windows and any other OS (mostly Linux) programmatically?

Tags: windows, linux, graphics, bitmap

I think the format of bitmap file, even device independent bitmap, as it is on windows is not compatible with other OS's.

Is there a way to transmit/share the raw bitmap image across OS's without encoding into and decoding from formats like PNG, JPEG etc?

I'll be using sockets.

edit: To add some clarity, I'd be needing to process images arriving at my Windows machine and transmit it further to a different machine, which would mostly be a Linux one where it would be processed further. The images arrive as bitmap and at high frequency. The processing and transmission must happen as quickly as possible, almost real time, so need to work with raw bitmap and not compressed images. For the transmission I'd be using sockets and tcp/ip. The images have to be at least 16M colors. And the image must be painted on the other machine, which is the crux of the doubt.

Comment: First, what are you really trying to do?  You don't want to convert to PNG, which is a lossless compressed format that will likely render fine elsewhere. But what do you want to do?  Also, RGB BMPs usually do render fine on other operating systems. It's just up to the user to have the appropriate software installed.

Comment: @selbie please see the added info.

Comment: The cost of compression/decompressing may actually be a win versus sending uncompressed image data over the wire.  It depends where the bottleneck is.  Video is usually compressed when streamed because it would be impossible to push it over most kinds of network links without compression.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Bitmap (AKA .BMP) format is a well-known format, you can find its description online. Many image viewers support it on OSes other than Windows.

Further, the network, the internet and sockets do not care in the slightest what data or in what format you're transmitting.

Comment: I would still refrain from sending uncompressed bitmaps over the network!

Comment: @ypnos Same here, but it's out of the scope of the question.

Comment: I have added some additional info, please check that.

Comment: Transmitting unpacked data is likely going to be far slower than transmitting packed, unpacking and packing again. But I think you need to make a test first as we don't know how fast your network is and how powerful your PCs are.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PGM/PPM files (PGM for single-channel, PPM for 3-channel). I personally have used these formats a fair bit because they are exceedingly easy to read/write. You can find the format specs [here (PGM)](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html) and [here (PPM)](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html).

The file headers plain ASCII are as follows:

```
<MAGIC>\n
<WIDTH> <HEIGHT> <MAX_VAL>\n
```

where `<MAGIC>` is "P5" for PGM and "P6" for PPM. `<WIDTH>` and `<HEIGHT>` are your width and height, as ASCII-encoded numbers. `<MAX_VAL>` is probably 255 for 8-bits-per-channel images. I have explicitly indicated newlines, but you can actually use any whitespace you like to separate the four fields in the header. It is however imperative that after `<MAX_VAL>`, a SINGLE white space character follows (though it can be any whitespace character).

Code sketch for writing a color bitmap on Linux:

```
unsigned char image[height][width][3];
// ... fill image ...
int fd = // open socket

// prepare and send header
char header[100] = {0};
int headerLen = snprintf(header, 100, "P6\n%d %d 255\n", width, height);
ssize_t written = write(fd, header, headerLen);
if(written != headerLen) ERROR;

// send body
written = write(fd, image, sizeof(image));
if(written != sizeof(image)) ERROR;
```

For reading, you obviously just need to read the magic number, width, and height.

```
int fieldsRead = fscanf(fd, "P6\n%d %d 255\n", &width, &height);
if(fieldsRead != 2) ERROR;
```

Then allocate storage for the body and read it:

```
unsigned char data = new unsigned char[width * height * 3]; // remember to delete later
ssize_t bytesRead = read(fd, data, width*height*3);
if(width*height*3 != bytesRead) {
  delete [] data;
  ERROR;
}
```

Of course, the read/write calls may have to be altered to work with your sockets, but the intent should be clear.